# Fadein effect before appending does not work jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

I want to make the data fadein before appending.. for some reason its not working

```
$this.find('.wrapper_middle').append(data).fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Hide it** first.  Then append it and fade it in.

```
$this.find('.wrapper_middle').hide().append(data).fadeIn(1000);
                             ^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score -1):

Change $this to $(this), make sure your data is valid, and make sure it is hidden or display:none before you try to fade it in.

Comment: you cant say this maybe there is a variable with `$this` name  it's different from `this` when we did something like this : `var $this=null`

Comment: `$this` is often used to store `$(this)` in, inside a scope. It prevent the code form performing `$(this)` more than necessary.

Comment: i usually use `$t` to storing a `$(t)` ! that's your opinion for this. sometimes we have our rules for coding. look at this : `var t='#someId'; $t=$(t); $t.hide().append(data).fadeIn(1000);`

Comment: is `$t` preventing `t` to perform what `t` doing in my project ?

Comment: I know and use the $this = $(this) practice...OP is a new user with one line of code...had to make an educated guess